# "Has" vs "present in" (for the constituents of a particular thing)

Tags: word-usage

In a math question if I talk about people (word problems) who have a certain number of things "has" sounds okay, but can I use "has" with "constituents of a particular thing" too?

> The number of molecules 24g of Magnesium **has** = ...........

Or

> The number of molecules **present in** 24g of Magnesium = ...........

Can "has" be used this way with things that are non-living?

Comment: Twenty-four grams of Magnesium contains [whatever].

Comment: Doesn't "has" sound okay to you @Lambie ?

Answer (score 1):

Acceptable examples:

- Twenty-four grams of Magnesium **contains** X molecules.

No, it does not sound okay using "has" like that:

It would have to be:

- Twenty-four grams Magnesium **has** [x] molecules.

By the way, living or non-living is irrelevant. **An atom has quarks and a dog has paws.**

Finally,

- The number of molecules present in A **is** B. You need an is for the second one.
- There are x molecules in Y grams of magnesium.

Generally, for statement-type sentences like this, we use: there are or there is.

And there is no need to use: **the number of molecules** in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using *has* with inanimate objects is acceptable, but the first version of this sentence is problematic because it requires more cognitive effort to interpret than the second version.

Notice that the math question is about a countable number of molecules and a non-countable quantity of Magnesium, given in a countable unit of measurement. Grammatically, I need to consider the 24 grams collectively as a single, non-countable entity. To answer the question, I need to calculate the number of molecules, using a countable number of grams. The concept is simple, but confirmation that *24g of Magnesium* is single entity does not come until the end of the sentence. This means the brain has to keep a greater number of possible interpretations in consideration for a longer period of time.

> The number of molecules 24g of Magnesium has = ...........

In this version, the subject of the sentence is *24g of Magnesium* (not *24g* or *Magnesium* alone).

> The number of molecules present in 24g of Magnesium = ...........

In this sentence, it is immediately clear that *number of molecules* is the subject of the sentence and that *24g of Magnesium* is the quantity of interest. Technically, the correct answer could be a formula (e.g., "molecules per gram times the number of grams) or a number, which still introduces more cognitive demand than necessary if the purpose of the question is strictly quantitative.

> How many molecules are present in 24g of Magnesium?

Let's take this an additional step beyond the grammatical question of *has* versus *present*. If you are a teacher and want to take additional precautions to invalidate creative answers, consider something like this:

> What is the total number of molecules present in exactly 24g of pure Magnesium?